# converting apache rewrite rules to nginx

Tags: php, nginx, rewrite, repository

Hello everyone,
               I am trying to create a UDID protected Cydia Repo but I cannot use it on nginx because of nginx does not use the .htaccess file. The file certain rewrite rules to make it run. Here are a copy of the Repo: https://github.com/ic0nic/UDID-repo Below is a copy of the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /your_repo_folder/
RewriteRule ^(Release)$ release.php
RewriteRule ^(Packages.*)$ package.php
```

Comment: Read documentation for [nginx Rewrite Module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule)

Answer (score 0):

Nginx don't have any plugin for Htaccess, but it has very nice language (like Perl) for config. Try this

```
location ~* ^/your_repo_folder/ {
rewrite ^(Release)$ release.php permanent;
rewrite ^(Packages.*)$ package.php permanent;
}
```